# Access violation error in doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I got this error while trying to add an element to my doubly linked list. I can't seem to find the mistake.

```
struct Pacijent
{
    char ime[10];
    [...]
    Pacijent *prev;
    Pacijent *next;
};

struct Lista
{
    Pacijent *front;
    Pacijent *back;
};

void assign(Pacijent p1, Pacijent p2)
{
    memcpy(&p1.ime, &p2.ime, sizeof(p1.ime));
    [...]
}
```

Here's the function that causes the mistake:

```
void insertBack(Pacijent p, Lista l)
{
    Pacijent *novi = (Pacijent*)malloc(sizeof(Pacijent));
    assign(*novi, p);
    if (l.back = NULL)
    {
        l.front = l.back = novi;
        novi->prev = NULL;
        novi->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        novi->prev = l.back; //here is where I get the error
        l.back->next = novi;
        novi->next = NULL;
        l.back = novi;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding part of *main* function:

```
Lista *lista = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    lista->back = lista->front = NULL;

    [...]
    Pacijent p1 = noviPacijent("Marko", "Markovic", "Milan", jmb1, 1.75, 70, 23);
    [...]

    insertBack(p1, *lista);
```

The *insertBack* function seems correct to me, I can't really locate the problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In `assign` you work with a copy of `novi`, so the call `assign(*nove, p)` has not the effect you probably want it to have. Try to work with pointers there. Same goes for `l` in `insertBack` (That might not be the only bug, it's just what I saw at first glance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd line of the `instertBack` function:  `if (l.back = NULL)`
You may want to change it to : `if (l.back == NULL)`

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I did that. Please excuse me while I go bang my head against the wall :D :ashamed: